# Displaying data from a mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason this php block keeps returning this error and I cant figure out why; i've setting out the same code in multiple styles and paradigms but it keeps returning the error

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result
```

But when I change the code to utilise the mysqli_result function php says it's undefined.

php block:

```
global $connection;
$query ="SELECT * FROM Members AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Lead);";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

while($row){
  echo "<li>".$row['FIRST_NAME']."</li>";
}
```

Comment: run thhis query:- `SELECT * FROM Members AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Lead);`  directly to sql end and see anything coming or not?

Comment: The query doesn't seem to be valid. Try running it directly

Comment: Query is clearly not valid. You can't have an `AND` clause with no `WHERE`.

try `SELECT * FROM Members WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Lead);`

Comment: ahh ok, I was trying to simulate an intersection and thought that the EXISTS was a good substitution for it; 

But why did the console return a php error and not an SQL query error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Replace `AND` with `WHERE` inside query

2.Put `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` inside `while()`

Do like below:-

```
global $connection;
$query ="SELECT * FROM Members WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Lead);";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo "<li>".$row['FIRST_NAME']."</li>";
}
```